# Enable password hashing in OpenLDAP

Tags: hash, openldap

How to enable password hashing in OpenLDAP?
It seems that OpenLDAP has `password-hash` set to `{SSHA}` by default, but whenever I enter a cleartext password in `userPassword` attribute using Apache Directory Studio, it is still stored in clear text.  I was expecting it to be converted to SSHA by OpenLDAP.

I also tried to put `password-hash {SSHA}` in `slapd.conf` file, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

When you tried to store `userPassword` attribute in add/modify LDAP operations,  `userPassword` value is stored as plain text. But you can override this behavior using `ppolicy_hash_cleartext` option in  `ppolicy` overlay module in OpenLDAP. Once you enable it, when client sends a plain text password, it is stored as SSHA by default. You can find configuration details on enabling hash password in OpenLADP from [here](http://xacmlinfo.org/2015/06/25/enable-hash-passwords-in-openldap/)

Answer (score 0):

When you set the attribute directly, you are setting the actual value, which can be hashed or not (as you have already discovered).

The following, quoted from [The FAQ](http://www.openldap.org/faq/data/cache/347.html):
First of all, make use of the 'slappasswd' utility to generate a password, so you can check if your PHP     routines are correct. (The slappasswd utility is part of the openldap distribution).
The command

```
slappasswd -h {SHA} -s supersecretpassword
```

may help.

Comment: In my case, the system/tool that sets the `userPassword` attribute doesn't use `slappasswd`

Comment: OK, then maybe you could explain your situation more?  It appeared that you were manually setting the password using Apache Directory Studio (my personal favorite LDAP browser/editor, btw).  What system/tool sets the userPassword, and how does it get the value it uses?

Comment: I have Java program which uses Spring LDAP to authenticate, add, delete or modify LDAP records.  What I am looking for is, my program will send a cleartext password and I want OpenLDAP to hash it using SSHA and store it.

Comment: ok, it's bending a bit outside my realm of expertise, but I will make one more addition -- the man page for slapd.conf mentions that the only operation affected by password-hash config value is "generation of user passwords stored in the userPassword attribute during processing of LDAP Password Modify Extended Operations (RFC 3062)".  And then it goes on to explicitly say "Note  that  this  option does not alter the normal user applications handling  of userPassword during LDAP Add, Modify, or other LDAP operations."

Comment: and adding up that man page, plus the spring ldap hint you've given, yields the following:  http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?55415-how-to-execute-extended-operations-in-spring-ldap

Comment: Thanks, seems like I need to hash my password using Java and send it to OpenLDAP `userPassword` attribute

Comment: @Praneeth No, it means you need to use the Password Modify Extended Operation. I posted Java code for it at the Oracle JNDI forum. Year or two ago. Google will find it.